# Error: write after end について

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptを使ってコードを書いていますが、以下のエラーが出てきます。

原因がよくわかりません。よろしくお願いします。

```
Error: write after end

at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:620:15)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:615:10)
    at /Users/a.shota/node_modules/iroha-helpers/iroha-atk/web.js:212:17
    at tryToString (fs.js:514:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:502:12)
```

Comment: エラー情報だけでは回答は難しいです。現象が再現するコードも追記し、現象が発生する手順も質問中に追記してください。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージから、「Error: write after end」というエラーが、ファイル _http_outgoing.js の615行目にある　"ServerResponse.write" のところで起きている事が判ります。

そして、「Error: write after end」なので、上記の"ServerResponse.write"より前に"ServerResponse.end"というようなコードが実行されているのだと思われます。

これをヒントに、ファイル _http_outgoing.js　を読み直してください。
読んでも判らない時には、そのプログラムを質問に追加して下さい。そうすれば、回答が得られるかもしれません。

[助言]　プログラムの内容が判らないのに、そのプログラムで起きるエラーの原因を推測することは無理です。